# T-SQL max date and min date between two date for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First, thanks for your time and your help!

I have two tables:

Table 1

```
PersId     name       lastName   city
---------------------------------------
1          John       Smith      Tirana
2          Leri       Nice       Tirana
3          Adam       fortsan    Tirana
```

Table 2

```
Id       PersId      salesDate
--------------------------------------------
1         1          2017-01-22 08:00:40 000
2         2          2017-01-22 09:00:00 000
3         1          2017-01-22 10:00:00 000
4         1          2017-01-22 20:00:00 000
5         3          2017-01-15 09:00:00 000
6         1          2017-01-21 09:00:00 000
7         1          2017-01-21 10:00:00 000
8         1          2017-01-21 18:55:00 000
```

I would like to see the first recent sales between two dates according to each city for **each day** I want to bring it empty if I do not have a sale

```
 SalesDate > '2017-01-17 09:00:00 000' 
 and SalesDate < '2017-01-23 09:00:00 000'
```

Table 2, id = 5 because the record is not in the specified date range

If I wanted my results to look like

```
Id      PersId     MinSalesDate                 MaxSalesDate             City  Date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1     2017-01-22 08:00:40 000  2017-01-22 20:00:00 000 Tirana 2017-01-22
2         2      2017-01-22 09:00:00 000  null                   Tirana 2017-01-22
3         3      null                     null                   Tirana 2017-01-22
4         1     2017-01-21 09:00:00 000  2017-01-21 18:55:00 000 Tirana 2017-01-21
5         2        null                     null                 Tirana 2017-01-21
6         3        null                     null                 Tirana 2017-01-21
7         1        null                     null                 Tirana 2017-01-20
8         2        null                     null                 Tirana 2017-01-20
9         3        null                     null                 Tirana 2017-01-20
```

vb.....

**It works for 1 day, but it does not work every day for 2 days**

```
 SELECT 
        T2.Id, T1.PersId, T2.MIN_salesDate, T2.MAX_salesDate, T1.City
    FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT MIN(Id) as Id, PersId, MIN(salesDate) as MIN_salesDate, MAX(salesDate) as MAX_salesDate 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                 *
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersId ORDER BY salesDate ASC) as RNKMIN
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersId ORDER BY salesDate DESC) as RNKMAX 
            FROM Table2 T2 
            WHERE salesDate Between '2017-01-17 09:00:00 000' And '2017-01-23 09:00:00 000'
        ) temp
        WHERE RNKMIN = 1 or RNKMAX = 1
        GROUP BY PersId
    ) T2
    on T1.PersId = T2.PersId
```

Comment: What is the `id` column in your expected output?

Comment: table 2 id column

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question 3 days ago?

Comment: But how, you're taking multiple sales rows and making one aggregate, so do you want the MIN() of `t2.id`?  Also, no matter what I choose, your example input does not match your example output.  For example, Person3 has no rows that would ever give id=3 in the output.

Comment: 3 days before the liability within 1 day I want to see the min and max sales for each day.

Comment: Why you have 2 rows for PersId = 1 , that is 1 and 4. ??

Comment: for customers selling on different days

Comment: MatBailie 
the above query is working correctly. But I want for every single day.

Comment: Got it. Thanks !! working on it.

Comment: Please try my solution. I have also updated your query.  You just need to add CAST(salesDate AS DATE) in the inner group by section. Thanks. Please see the both the updated solutions in the below section.

Comment: Yes. See my answer given below from the answers section.

Comment: @PawanKumar I am trying.

Comment: Sure. Please update if any changes are required or not. Thanks !

Comment: @PawanKumar  I'm adding the output result up – Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Cool thanks..Changing the query for you.  !

Comment: The data you have given is very different from the input you have given...

Comment: @PawanKumar there was no sales on the first and last day of the day

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(
PersId INT,
name NVARCHAR(50),
city NVARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(
Id INT,
PersId INT,
salesDate NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1, 'John', 'Tirana')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(2, 'Leri', 'Tirana')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(3, 'Adam', 'Tirana')

INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(1, 1, '2017-01-22 08:00:40')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(2, 2, '2017-01-22 09:00:00')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(3, 1, '2017-01-22 10:00:00')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(4, 1, '2017-01-22 20:00:00')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(5, 3, '2017-01-15 09:00:00')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(6, 1, '2017-01-21 09:00:00')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(7, 1, '2017-01-21 10:00:00')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(8, 1, '2017-01-21 18:55:00')



SELECT T1.PersId, GroupTable.MinSalesDate, GroupTable.MaxSalesDate, T1.city
FROM @Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT max(salesDate) as 'MaxSalesDate', CASE WHEN min(salesDate) <> max(salesDate) THEN min(salesDate) ELSE NULL END AS 'MinSalesDate', PersId
FROM @Table2
WHERE salesDate > '2017-01-17 09:00:00' and SalesDate < '2017-01-23 09:00:00'
GROUP BY DATEPART(day, salesDate) , PersId) AS GroupTable
ON T1.PersId = GroupTable.PersId
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: OP also needs `Id` column in output

Comment: I want the max and min values ​​to be null for non-recordable days. I'm adding the output result up –

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this -** Please let us know if you require any modification.

```
SELECT a.PersId, MIN(salesDate) MinSalesDate , CASE WHEN  MIN(salesDate) = MAX(salesDate) 
THEN NULL ELSE MAX(salesDate)  END MaxSalesDate , a.city FROM Table1 a
FULL JOIN Table2 b ON a.PersId = b.PersId
AND SalesDate > '2017-01-17 09:00:00' and SalesDate < '2017-01-23 09:00:00'
WHERE a.PersId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.PersId,a.city,CAST(salesDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY a.PersId
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PersId      MinSalesDate            MaxSalesDate            city
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------
1           2017-01-22 08:00:40.000 2017-01-22 20:00:00.000 Tirana
2           2017-01-22 09:00:00.000 NULL                    Tirana
3           NULL                    NULL                    Tirana
1           2017-01-21 09:00:00.000 2017-01-21 18:55:00.000 Tirana

(4 rows affected)
```

**I have updated your query also. Please see.**

```
SELECT 
        T2.Id, T1.PersId, T2.MIN_salesDate, T2.MAX_salesDate, T1.City
    FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT MIN(Id) as Id, PersId, MIN(salesDate) as MIN_salesDate, MAX(salesDate) as MAX_salesDate 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                 *
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersId ORDER BY salesDate ASC) as RNKMIN
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersId ORDER BY salesDate DESC) as RNKMAX 
            FROM Table2 T2 
            WHERE salesDate Between '2017-01-17 09:00:00' And '2017-01-23 09:00:00'
        ) temp
        WHERE RNKMIN = 1 or RNKMAX = 1
        GROUP BY PersId,CAST(salesDate AS DATE)
    ) T2
    on T1.PersId = T2.PersId
```

**OUTPUT from  your query**

```
Id          PersId      MIN_salesDate           MAX_salesDate           City
----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------
6           1           2017-01-21 09:00:00.000 2017-01-21 09:00:00.000 Tirana
4           1           2017-01-22 20:00:00.000 2017-01-22 20:00:00.000 Tirana
2           2           2017-01-22 09:00:00.000 2017-01-22 09:00:00.000 Tirana
NULL        3           NULL                    NULL                    Tirana

(4 rows affected)
```

Comment: it comes for every day but there is a problem. 1 person has 1 day record 1 day no record day is not null null. Can you check?

Comment: Not getting. Can you please show data for which you are not getting? example?

Comment: I want the max and min values ​​to be null for non-recordable days. I'm adding the output result up

Comment: i m adding result up